# Angular route with $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-routing, route-provider

I'm trying to understand the routing before I start building my app but it doesn't seem to work.

I have a basic app for tests in which I created 3 html files matching 3 different views and I wish to change the displayed view depending on the routes.

But I always see the index view.

Here are the files :

app.js :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('BalrogApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'BalrogApp.controllers'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../index.html'
      })
      .when('/requests', {
        templateUrl: '../views/requestsList.html'
      })
      .when('/projects', {
        templateUrl: '../views/projectsList.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/lol'
      });

  }]);
```

requestsController.js :

```
'use strict';

var requestsControllerModule = angular.module('BalrogApp.controllers', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

requestsControllerModule.controller('requestsController', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $routeParams) {

  this.studentName = "Request";
  this.studentMark = 75;

});
```

projectsController.js :

```
'use strict';

var projectsControllerModule = angular.module('BalrogApp.controllers', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

projectsControllerModule.controller('projectsController', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $routeParams) {

  this.studentName = "Project";
  this.studentMark = 75;

});
```

The html files are almost the same except for some words and for the controller associated to each of them.

Here are the few lines that change between html wiews :

index.html :

```
index view
<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="requestsController as rc">
  <div class="span2">{{rc.studentName}} </div>
</div>
```

requestsList.html :

```
Request view
<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="requestsController as r">
  <div class="span2">{{r.studentName}} </div>
</div>
```

projectsList.html

```
Project view
<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="projectsController as p">
  <div class="span2">{{p.studentName}} </div>
</div>
```

Byt no matter what the route is, if I added '/projects' or '/requests' to the url, I stay on the index view.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have `ng-view` attribute (or element) on your index.html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `ng-view` attribute or element set in your `index.html`. If it is absent the router won't work.
Another good practice would be to set your view controller on the router, like so:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('<route_name>', {
    templateUrl: '../<tempate>.html',
    controller: '<controller_name>',
    controllerAs: 'myController'
  })
```

Comment: I have an empty `<ng-view>` at a point in `index.html`. But I might need to add more things ?
Maybe there are issues because my controllers module is not the same as my app module ?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** On your base file (usually index.html), make sure you have an `ng-view` directive that will be used to load all the **partial** views

**2.** Are all your html templates in the same location as the base file? If yes, the instead of having the `templateUrl` as `"../index.html"` you could try setting it to `"/index.html"` instead. The first checks for the html file outside of the directory where the base file is located, while the second checks for it in the same directory